# checkboxes in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in my project, I want to add a column with checkboxes which while rendering will be checked based on the object which binds the table.
In the object, there is a field with a boolean value which will determine if the checkbox will be checked or not, and after making changes in the checkboxes, the changed values should be available.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set filter type checkbox

```
passed: {
    title: 'Passed',
    filter: {
      type: 'checkbox',
      config: {
        true: 'Yes',
        false: 'No',
        resetText: 'clear',
      },
    },
  },
```

in your data you need to pass checkbox value

```
data = [
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
  email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
  passed: 'Yes',
},
]
```

Try this example [Checkbox, Select and Completer filter types](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/filter/advanced-example-filters.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I can not provide you a full sample code right now but you should define a column for your checkbox. Provide a boolean value for that column. Don't forget to add

> 'type: custom'

It renders the Component you provide. I used a component named MyCheckboxComponent

```
<nb-checkbox [ngModel]="selected"></nb-checkbox>
```

nb-checkbox is in nebular library.

```
settings = {
    columns: {
        checkBox: {
          type: 'custom',
          filter: false,
          width: '10px',
          renderComponent: MyCheckboxComponent
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more complete example, because for me it doesn't render anything

Comment: https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/checkbox/examples#nbcheckboxcomponent if this link doesn't help, I will write an example